# Cannot import name 'Instalysis' from 'instagramy'

Tags: python-3.x

I cannot figure out what this error requires... any ideas for a Python newbie? All pre requisites are installed... this is version 3.9 64-bit.

Details: "ADO.NET: Python script error.
ImportError: cannot import name 'Instalysis' from 'instagramy' (C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instagramy_*init*_.py)
"

Here's the test script I'm running:

```
from instagramy import Instalysis

# Instagram user_id of ipl teams
teams = ["chennaiipl", "mumbaiindians",
         "royalchallengersbangalore", "kkriders",
         "delhicapitals", "sunrisershyd", 
         "kxipofficial"]
  
data = Instalysis(teams)
  
# return the dataframe
data_frame = data.analyis()
data_frame
```

Answer (score 1):

The instagramy package doesn't have the 'Instalysis' section to it. But it does have these:
`from instagramy import InstagramUser`
This will give uyou all of the info also I saw that you had parentheses at `data_frame = data.analyis()`
You will recieve an error if you have them as it isn't an executable function.
Go have a look at the pypi page here: [Pypi- Instagramy](https://pypi.org/project/instagramy/#Instagram-Location-details)
Hope this could help!